# Get table row based on radio button using prototype/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, html-table, prototypejs

I have an html table that has a name and a radio button like so:

```
<table id="cars">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Car Name</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="car">Ford Focus</td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="selectedCar" name="selectedCar" value="8398"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="car">Lincoln Navigator</td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="selectedCar" name="selectedCar" value="2994"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Select Car" onclick="selectCar()"></input>
```

I want to be able to select a radio button, then click another button and get the value of the radio button (which is a unique ID) as well as the car name text (like Ford Focus).  How should I code the selectCar method?  I've tried a few things like:

```
val1 = $('tr input[name=selectedCar]:checked').parent().find('#cars').html();
val1 = $("td input[name='selectedCar']:checked").parents().find('.cars').html();
val1 = $('selectedCar').checked;
```

but I can't get the proper values.

I'm using prototype, but the solution can be plain Javascript as well.

Comment: IDs of elements have to be unique!

Comment: @Marcel Korpel So if the ID has to be unique, how can I see which one is checked? The table is built dynamically and could have many rows so I need any easy way to loop through them to see which one was checked and get the corresponding info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**All IDs have to be unique!**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

You can try with this HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="car">Ford Focus</td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="selectedCar1" name="selectedCar" value="8398"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="car">Lincoln Navigator</td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="selectedCar2" name="selectedCar" value="2994"></td>
</tr>
```

After this, you can test using:

```
val1 = $('selectedCar1').checked;
```

(returns `true` or `false`).

Or, if you want to grab the selected value, use [getElementsByName](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259):

```
function getCarValue()
{
    var theCars = document.getElementsByName("selectedCar");
    var i = theCars.length;
    while (i--) {
        if(theCars[i].checked)
             return theCars[i].value;

    }
}
```