# Edit a row from a selected radion button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to edit a row from a selected radio button in a table?

here is a screenshot when i added some data:
https://imgur.com/H4RAbGs

here is the table : (i am using bootstrap)

```html
<div class="table table-responsive" id="halaman1">
      <table class="table" id="table1">
     
        <th>index</th>
        <th>Kode Mhs</th>
        <th>Nama Mhs</th>
        <th>Angkatan</th>
        <th>Jurusan</th>
        <th>Alamat</th>
        <th>Telp</th>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the code for adding data to the table:

```js
function fungsiTambah() {
    var index = document.getElementById('index').value;
    var kode = document.getElementById('kode').value;
    var nama = document.getElementById('nama').value;
    var angkatan = document.getElementById('angkatan').value;
    var jurusan = document.getElementById('jurusan').value;
    var alamat = document.getElementById('alamat').value;
    var telp = document.getElementById('telp').value;

    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length / 2 + 1); 

    var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    var cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    var cel5 = newRow.in
```

```html
These are the form elements :
<form>

index :
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="index Mhs" name: "index" id="index">

<br>Kode Mhs :
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Kode Mhs" name: "kode" id="kode">

<br>Nama Lengkap :
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Nama Lengkap" name: "nama" id="nama">

<br>Angkatan :
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Angkatan" name: "angkatan" id="angkatan">

<br>Jurusan :
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Jurusan" name: "jurusan" id="jurusan">

<br>Alamat :
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Alamat" name: "alamat" id="alamat">

<br>Telp :
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Telp" name: "telp" id="telp">
          </form>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: i updated the image, thank you.

Comment: Nope, still its showing index column as checkbox. On clicking the checkbox, the modal should be displayed with selected value right?

Comment: I think it is radion button, sir. What i mean i wanted to do is change the data of the row where the radio button is checked/selected only. sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: No problem.Hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999398/get-table-row-based-on-radio-button-using-prototype-javascript